# link "make" command to lib and include

Tags: compiling, make, libraries

I want to use `make` command and link it to the include and lib path.

I am using :

```
make -I /path_to_include  - L /path_to_lib
```

but it gives me:

```
nothing to be done for /path_to_lib
```

(The path is correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` does not accept options like `-L /path/to/somewhere` - these are arguments that need to be given to the compiler and `make` will not pass them on. You probably need to edit the `Makefile` appropriately.

Depending on the `Makefile`, it will often use a variable like `CFLAGS`, `LIBS` or `LDFLAGS` to pass extra options to the compiler. You can set these when you run `make`: `LIBS=-lmylib LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/mylib make`. This relies on the `Makefile` having been written to use such variables however, which one generated by a system like `autoconf` probably will, but one written by hand may not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below “make” command to link lib and include,

```
make <filename_without_extension> LDLIBS="-l<lib1> -l<lib2>"
```

suppose you have server1.cpp file to compile using make command,

```
make server1 LDLIBS="-lcpprest -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/" CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/include/"
```

Output will expand the compilation command as,

```
g++ -I/usr/include/  -L/usr/lib/  server1.cpp  -lcpprest -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -o server1
```